# How do you build dynamic linear models based on very frequent time series data?

Tags: r, dlm

I like to be able to use dynamic linear modelling (DLM) on a time series data to perform forecast. I am currently using lm function but I like explore dlm to see the difference. My data looks like this:

```
    structure(list(DATE = structure(c(1389287553, 1389287583, 1389287613, 
1389287643, 1389287673, 1389287703, 1389287733, 1389287763, 1389287793, 
1389287823, 1389287853, 1389287883, 1389287913, 1389287943, 1389287973, 
1389288003, 1389288033, 1389288063, 1389288093, 1389288123, 1389288153, 
1389288183, 1389288213, 1389288243, 1389288273, 1389288303, 1389288333, 
1389288363, 1389288393, 1389288423, 1389288453, 1389288483, 1389288513, 
1389288543, 1389288573, 1389288603, 1389288633, 1389288663, 1389288693, 
1389288723, 1389288753, 1389288783, 1389288813, 1389288843, 1389288873, 
1389288903, 1389288933, 1389288963, 1389288993, 1389289023, 1389289053, 
1389289083, 1389289113, 1389289143, 1389289173, 1389289203, 1389289233, 
1389289264, 1389289294, 1389289324, 1389289354, 1389289384, 1389289414, 
1389289444, 1389289474, 1389289504, 1389289534, 1389289564, 1389289594, 
1389289624, 1389289654, 1389289684, 1389289714, 1389289744, 1389289774, 
1389289804, 1389289834, 1389289864, 1389289894, 1389289924, 1389289954, 
1389289984, 1389290014, 1389290044, 1389290074, 1389290104, 1389290134, 
1389290165, 1389290195, 1389290225, 1389290255, 1389290285, 1389290315, 
1389290345, 1389290375, 1389290405, 1389290435, 1389290465, 1389290495, 
1389290525, 1389290555, 1389290586, 1389290616, 1389290646, 1389290676, 
1389290706, 1389290736, 1389290766, 1389290796, 1389290826, 1389290856, 
1389290886, 1389290916, 1389290946, 1389290976, 1389291006, 1389291036, 
1389291067, 1389291097, 1389291127, 1389291157, 1389291187, 1389291217, 
1389291247, 1389291277, 1389291307, 1389291337, 1389291367, 1389291397, 
1389291427, 1389291457, 1389291487, 1389291517, 1389291547, 1389291577, 
1389291607, 1389291637, 1389291667, 1389291697, 1389291727, 1389291757, 
1389291787, 1389291817, 1389291847, 1389291877, 1389291907, 1389291937, 
1389291967, 1389291997, 1389292027, 1389292057, 1389292087, 1389292117, 
1389292147, 1389292177, 1389292207, 1389292237, 1389292267, 1389292297, 
1389292327, 1389292357, 1389292387, 1389292417, 1389292447, 1389292478, 
1389292508, 1389292538, 1389292568, 1389292598, 1389292628, 1389292658, 
1389292688, 1389292718, 1389292748, 1389292778, 1389292808, 1389292838, 
1389292868, 1389292898, 1389292928, 1389292958, 1389292988, 1389293018, 
1389293048, 1389293078, 1389293108, 1389293138, 1389293168, 1389293198, 
1389293228, 1389293258, 1389293288, 1389293318, 1389293348, 1389293378, 
1389293408, 1389293438, 1389293468, 1389293498, 1389293528), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), pc = c(7.29, 7.4, 7.15, 7.63, 7.46, 7.35, 
8.1, 8.05, 7.9, 7.84, 7.86, 7.76, 7.63, 7.52, 7.21, 7.58, 7.98, 
7.99, 7.16, 7.28, 7.07, 7.37, 6.93, 7.16, 7.14, 7.18, 6.97, 7.71, 
7.19, 7.16, 7.29, 7.11, 7.08, 7.24, 7.31, 7.2, 8.23, 9.18, 8.13, 
7.6, 7.53, 7.49, 7.18, 7.76, 7.03, 7.23, 7.23, 7.5, 7.18, 6.96, 
7.08, 7.03, 7.2, 7.11, 7, 7.07, 7.92, 8.56, 8.05, 7.29, 7.21, 
7.06, 6.94, 7.19, 7.02, 7.24, 7.76, 7.2, 7.32, 7.58, 7.68, 7.45, 
7.52, 7.21, 7.22, 7.16, 7.57, 7.25, 7.32, 7.67, 7.23, 7.09, 7.12, 
7.01, 7.08, 7.37, 7.25, 7.07, 7.26, 7.34, 7.01, 7.02, 7.15, 6.83, 
7.1, 7.26, 7.58, 7.69, 7.75, 8, 7.8, 7.94, 7.64, 7.07, 7.13, 
7.19, 7.39, 7.15, 7.41, 7.1, 7.11, 7.36, 7.04, 7.14, 7.04, 7.33, 
8.37, 9.05, 7.85, 7.33, 7.62, 7.88, 7.29, 7.29, 7.64, 7.65, 8.18, 
8.34, 7.67, 7.74, 7.49, 8.11, 7.55, 7.77, 7.57, 7.26, 7.31, 7.77, 
6.92, 6.98, 7.09, 7.56, 7.16, 6.99, 6.92, 7.33, 7.03, 7.34, 7.27, 
7.16, 7, 7.06, 6.92, 7.1, 6.83, 7.03, 7.64, 8.59, 7.27, 7.39, 
7.21, 7.62, 7.34, 7.96, 7.03, 7.13, 7.06, 7.11, 7.05, 7.05, 7.11, 
6.81, 6.78, 7.02, 6.82, 7.03, 7.79, 8.26, 7.25, 7.06, 7.1, 6.93, 
6.96, 7.01, 7.24, 7.03, 7.42, 7.09, 7.31, 7.14, 7.15, 6.93, 7.52, 
7.51, 7.16, 7.09, 7.45, 7.12, 7.08, 7.06)), .Names = c("DATE", 
"pc"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 
19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 
45L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 61L, 63L, 65L, 67L, 69L, 
71L, 73L, 75L, 77L, 79L, 81L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 89L, 91L, 93L, 95L, 
97L, 99L, 101L, 103L, 105L, 107L, 109L, 111L, 113L, 115L, 117L, 
119L, 121L, 123L, 125L, 127L, 129L, 131L, 133L, 135L, 137L, 139L, 
141L, 143L, 145L, 147L, 149L, 151L, 153L, 155L, 157L, 159L, 161L, 
163L, 165L, 167L, 169L, 171L, 173L, 175L, 177L, 179L, 181L, 183L, 
185L, 187L, 189L, 191L, 193L, 195L, 197L, 199L, 201L, 203L, 205L, 
207L, 209L, 211L, 213L, 215L, 217L, 219L, 221L, 223L, 225L, 227L, 
229L, 231L, 233L, 235L, 237L, 239L, 241L, 243L, 245L, 247L, 249L, 
251L, 253L, 255L, 257L, 259L, 261L, 263L, 265L, 267L, 269L, 271L, 
273L, 275L, 277L, 279L, 281L, 283L, 285L, 287L, 289L, 291L, 293L, 
295L, 297L, 299L, 301L, 303L, 305L, 307L, 309L, 311L, 313L, 315L, 
317L, 319L, 321L, 323L, 325L, 327L, 329L, 331L, 333L, 335L, 337L, 
339L, 341L, 343L, 345L, 347L, 349L, 351L, 353L, 355L, 357L, 359L, 
361L, 363L, 365L, 367L, 369L, 371L, 373L, 375L, 377L, 379L, 381L, 
383L, 385L, 387L, 389L, 391L, 393L, 395L, 397L, 399L), class = "data.frame")
```

Can somebody start me out about how would you go about building a DLM based on this type of time series data? Any insight/help/guide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of DLM do you want? If you just want to extend the `lm()` model with lagged version of covariates or the response, take a look at the **dynlm** package. If you want to set up a DLM in state-space form, try the **dlm** package. If you can be clearer about the model you want to fit (the class of DLMs is huge!) you may get more specific help here.

Comment: Not what you want to hear, but if the sample size here of 20 is typical, your scope for building any kind of complicated time series model is limited.

Comment: @Nick Cox, this data is just a sample. The actual data is 30 seconds data with thousands of raws.

Comment: @Matt Krause, I used lm but, not happy with the results. It is a straight line which is not really resembles the truth. I like to explore DLM. With this given data, what would you recommend?

Comment: That's good news, but if the real data are thousands, what chance have we of making good recommendations from 20?

Comment: @Nick Cox, I've update the post.